# Google Protocol Buffers - serialize to byte array

Tags: c#, serialization, memorystream, protocol-buffers

I'm following the tutorial for using Google Protocol Buffers for C#. I don't see an example for converting an object into a byte array - does anyone know how to do that? I've auto-generated a FilePath classes using the protoc compiler and have this so far:

```
FilePath fp = new FilePath
{
    Path = "TestPath",
    RealTimeMultiple = 5.0f
};
```

So, I need to know how to properly serialize the fp object without the use of BinaryFormatter.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `Google.Protobuf` nuget package, you can just use:

```
using Google.Protobuf;

...

byte[] bytes = fp.ToByteArray();
```

You need the `using` directive for `Google.Protobuf` to make the [`IMessage.ToByteArray`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/7762f163a4150772be9a0eae3a285ff9b1eb3246/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/MessageExtensions.cs#L107) extension method available - that may be what you were missing before.

Comment: Thanks - had no idea it was that simple. Do you have an example or know how I would then go about sending the byte array using the WriteTo method? I've appended more details in the question.

Comment: @Roka545: What do you mean by "sending the byte array"? If you want to write the message to a stream, use `WriteTo(stream)` instead. Your additional bit of question doesn't really help - so you already know how to write to a stream (although normally you wouldn't write to a MemoryStream unless you were doing something else with the stream). So you know how to write to a stream or to convert it to a byte array... so what else do you need to know? You haven't really explained what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: I'm using Protobuf along with nanomsg to send/receive data between nodes. Basically, I have two nodes that are able to send/receive messages between each other. One node will create and serialize the fp object and send it to the other. The receiving node will then receive that data, deserialize it, and extract any info from it.

Comment: @Roka545: That doesn't really help me in terms of what you're missing here - never having used nanomsg, I've no idea what it requires. If you know how to write to a stream, and you know how to create a byte array, what else do you need? (Given that I've answered your original question, I suggest you roll back your edit, then ask a separate question which is nanomsg+protobuf specific, if you still have concerns. Please focus on making it really clear what you're asking for, to avoid going back and forth like this.)